# How to display different images in launch screen depending on size classes

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a LaunchScreen.xib that needs to show slightly different logos for different device formats. I understand how to set constraints conditionally using the "Vary for Traits" button, but I also need to replace the actual image set that the UIImageView is using. I know there is some kind of workaround because I have a sample file where this is happening, but I don't know how they achieved it (see the grayed-out images in the screenshot). I cannot use code because this is a launch screen, so any solution needs to be possible with interface builder.

Conditional image use that I would like to replicate

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have different images for iPhone and iPad (watch, TV) in your asset catalog for one resource.

[image]

You can also have different image for different width, height (traits based) and gamut that you specify in the Image drop down in the LaunchScreen.storyboard (see the little plus sign).

[image]

I think the latter is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. The latter solution does what I was looking for.